# SwiftUI graphic issues on setting offset

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag

Is this the best way to move a stack in a view?
The HStack wrapped by ZStack is producing graphic issues when its becomes offset on drag gesture.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
            
            }
            .offset(x: offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ (value) in
                        withAnimation{
                            offset = value.translation.width
                        }
                    })
                    .onEnded({ (value) in
                        withAnimation{
                            offset = CGFloat(0)
                        }
                    })
            )
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine with xcode 12.5.1 iOS 14.5

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Are you just looking to have the user be able to move the view back and forth?

Comment: @RajaKishan im working with Xcode 13 & iOS 15

Comment: @Yrb i want to build stack of cards